# Is it safe to get all AD Groups for a Principal with recursion?

Tags: .net, active-directory

Considering the following .Net recursive code:

```
public void FindAllGroups(PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups)
{
    foreach (Principal p in groups.ToList())
    {
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> childGroups = p.GetGroups();
        if (childGroups.Count() > 0)
        {
            FindAllGroups(childGroups);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a risk that this code will end-up recursing forever?

Put it as an Active Directory matter, is it possible to have cycles in nested groups in AD?

Is `GetGroups()` the right way to do what I want: List all groups?

I am quite unsure how groups can be linked to one another and would be thankful if someone could link me any piece of documentation that explains the matter (I did not find it by myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/180740/can-an-active-directory-group-indirectly-include-itself-in-a-cycle) then:

> is it possible to have cycles in nested groups in AD?

would be YES.

Therefore you need to avoid processing the same group another time (eg. keep a list, a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) perhaps, of groups already processed and check before recursing).

Comment: Ok. Groups can have any relationships then? Two groups can "own" the same group for instance?

Comment: That's a stupid question from me, the answer is: Of course. Since users can belong to several groups, a group can also belong to several groups. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @thibaultd Mostly yes (IIRC) but there are exceptions. Eg. Ownership and "Managed By" are singular.